# Unable to push docker image to github package using github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-push, github-packages

Hi I am trying to push docker images to github packages using workflow. Below is my workflow.

```
 - name: Log in to the Container registry
      uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
      with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This step passes and I am able to login. Below is my next step.

```
 - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      id: meta
      uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
      with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

    - name: Build and push Docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
      with:
          context: ./CharteringExecutionPlatform/
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

In this step I am successfully able to build docker image and tag it. Workflow fails when pushing docker image to github package. I am getting below error

> ERROR: denied: requested access to the resource is denied Error:
> buildx call failed with: ERROR: denied: requested access to the
> resource is denied

I am not sure what I am missing here. Can someone help me? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting the correct tags in the extract metedata step

```
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: ['6.0.x' ]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=semver,pattern={{version}}
            type=semver,pattern={{major}}.{{minor}}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          file: subdir/Dockerfile
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```